# array inside while loop to count classify countries

Tags: php

I have a problem with array inside the while loop, I want to classify countries and for each country how many times are repeated in the database and here is my code and the result.

[image: my code]

[image: the output]

Answer (score 0):

1st *Stop* using `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated since several years!

2nd you're selecting all rows from the `users`. As you described you want something like:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(country) FROM users GROUP BY country
```